# Eagle switch nets in schematic editor

Tags: eaglecad

Is it possible to swap two nets in Eagle schemtaic editor. For example, I have two LCD connectors and PCB is very badly routed, so I need to swap some nets on second LCD connector. Is this possible with single command or I have to do following:

1. Memorize name of first and second net
2. Delete both nets
3. Create new net and assign to it second net name
4. Create new net and assign to it first net name

Here is a screenshot of situation:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that what you're trying to do isn't possible with a single command.  It's possible to write a ULP for such operation.  I'm not aware of an existing ULP like that, though.

But here's a fairly efficient way of swapping nets, which doesn't involve memorizing net names.  In your schematic, the nets are just stubs (as opposed to a continuous wire going from one pin to another).  For the purposes of explanation: *left hand side (l.h.s.)* is the end which you want to keep unchanged, *right hand side (r.h.s.)* is the end which you want to rearrange.

1. Delete the stubs and net labels at the pins which you want to rearrange (r.h.s.).  Don't delete the entire net.  Keep the stubs and labels on l.h.s.
2. Copy the stubs from l.h.s. to their new pins on r.h.s.
3. Add net labels.

This works on my Windows installation of Eagle 6.3.0